# Audio Graph: Which approach to take on input monitoring

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

My task is to monitor the computer’s audio inputs (mics, line-ins) and to display them visually in sync.

I am new to **AudioGraph** class so given the basic [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) and very basic class [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph) I feel that I need advice on how to continue.

I can see two major approaches but both are imperfect.

### Audio frame output node

- Create a Graph
- For each device input node create an audio frame output node
- Feed it from the device input node by calling method AddOutgoingConnection()
- Define a handler to the QuantumStarted event create a buffer and pass it to data processing.

This approach creates a device input node/audio frame output node per input device and exposes the data frames without much difficulties.
However, since all audio frame output nodes use a single event handler, the handler has no way to detect the origin of a given frame, that is, the audio frame output node that signaled the event and passed the frame.

Here’s perhaps a solution:
Create a graph per input device. Here, the handler will process frames from the known origin. I am not sure it is OK to create several audio graphs in a single application.
In addition, there’s a frame-sync problem because AudioFrame.SystemRelativeTime is always null (bug?).

### Adding a custom audio effect

A custom audio effect has a structure similar to that of  a QuantumStarted handler. It is called periodically and supplied with input and output frames.
If we create a NO-OP effect and attach it to every input node we have access to all input frames without implementing an effect.
There’s still a sever problem with synchronization between frames that originate from different inputs.

I’ll be grateful if someone will be able to help me decide on the correct approach and to show me how to solve the sync problems.

Comment: Could I know what actually you want to?  Several input devices record at same time and  into one output?  Like [MeeDJ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/meedj/9wzdncrdcm6z) but input are devices instead of files?   What the outputs, files or devices(for example, speaker)?  What  "input monitoring" mean? If I misunderstand you please kindly tell me.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I am thinking of multy-band oscilloscope.